# Is it possible to automatically insert version number in code using bazaar?

Tags: bazaar

I am currently working with a coding project using the bzr (bazaar) source code management software.  I would like to include the version number in the file code of my project

So that I could call the variable "VERSION" and echo out my current working version.
Within the code be able to do this:

```
var VERSION = ###;
```

Where ### is the current version number.  Is this possible? or do I have to inspect the bzr info on a file and increment my version manually prior to committing new code?

Answer (score 3):

The only solution I know is the Keyword plugin for Bazaar:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/keywords-plugin.html

(This points to https://launchpad.net/bzr-keywords but the first link has more explanation).

Steps:

1. Get the plugin

   `bzr branch lp:bzr-keywords`
2. Install plugin (basically copy it in bazaar **plugins** install folder)
3. Get the help

   `bzr help keywords`

Once installed, commit your code with the keywords inside, it will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to invoke the 'bzr version-info' command, which can output the version number in various convenient ways.